# Filling table cell (iphone) in objective C in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am displaying the data in table cell and I am downloading the data using the web service. 
The data is huge, so it takes some time to download it and then display it. 
I need to provide some solution.
 I was thinking of downloading some data initially and then once the screen displays the information, then in the background will download rest of the data.
 In this case the application will not look sluggish.
If there is any other solution, please guide..

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement this code

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"LeaveRequestTableViewCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                   reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

This will make your application fast as only the visible cells on the phone will be loaded.